# download file from google drive using javascript

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api

I searched many places however no luck to find a help.

I want to use javascript to download file from google drive as following codes:

```
function downloadFile(fileUrl, accessToken) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', fileUrl);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + accessToken);
    xhr.onload = function() {
        alert("xhr=" + xhr.responseText);};
    xhr.onerror = function() {alert("xhr error");};
    xhr.send(); 
}
```

in code, fileUrl, accessToken have been obtained from a web service created to retrieve those ino.

However, this java function was not working, responseText is empty, and readyState was 4. anyone can help? thanks.

rgds
brent

Comment: Were there any messages in your browser's JavaScript console? What was the status of the request in your browser's Developer Tools' Net tab?

Comment: Cross origin issues come to mind, and is the file XML in the first place?

Comment: @mplungjan — Why would the file need to be XML? It's being accessed with `responseText`.

Comment: XMLhttprequest normally expects valid xml

Comment: @mplungjan — No, it doesn't. It has a stupid name, that's all. (The name came because "Oh! XML is new and shiny! If we call the ActiveX control something with XML in, then we can persuade higher up people to let us build it.")

Comment: Try to dl invalid XML in chrome. It will not let you.

Comment: Quentin: I used IE 9 since Google chrome had cross region error. There was nothing in browser's javascript console, in network tab of Ie

Comment: there was a status of 401, http unauthorized. does it mean google drive doesn't allow such way to retrieve file?

Comment: No, we do allow. There is working example on https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/get on the JS tab. Are you sure that the access token you are using is valid?

Comment: thanks for reminder. I found access token was invalid, now it is ok.

Comment: I found an issue. I had an access token, credential.getExpiresInSeconds returned 7131, but at almost same time, https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo?access_token=xxxx returned 3514, it was a big difference, this was the reason why my access token was invalid. may I know which seconds returned was correct?

Comment: Sounds like a bug, because all access tokens are not valid more than an hour. 7131 seconds is unrealistic.